# How to obtain Normal and Covariance of the Estimated normal with noisy points in PCL?

Tags: point-cloud-library

I have a point cloud in which each point is represented by its mean and is covariance. I would like to obtain the mean and the covariance of the normal vector estimated for each point. How could I do this in PCL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the following process can give you a good estimate:

1. Create a new point-cloud that is sampled from the distribution of your input cloud (mean and is covariance of each point).
2. Estimate normals for the above (sampled) cloud.
3. Repeat N times.

At the end of this process you will get N different normal vectors for each point. Now you just need to calculate their mean & covariance.